# TeamCity VCS Server side checkout changes text files from unicode to UTF-8

Tags: unicode, build, teamcity, perforce

I have a build that is checking out code from Perforce, but when I try to set the "VCS checkout mode" to server side, I know it does a copy of the workspace (and code) to the build agent. Well I discovered that it is clobbering some files we have in our build that are similar to text files. It is changing them from UNICODE BOM to UTF-8 and the tool we use to parse those files fails in the build.

Does anyone have an idea as to why TeamCity server side checkout and copy would be doing this? Does anyone know how to remedy this situation? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help, I figured out that the files that were in question where of type utf16 and there is actually an option in the Team City VCS Root configuration to enabled handling of utf16 files (Support UTF-16 encoding). This seemed to have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You say the clobbering only happens on TeamCity. Can you recheck how it behaves locally? Delete the file from your filesystem and run `p4 sync -f FILE` to get it fresh from the server. Is the BOM preserved?

If you can reproduce the loss of the BOM locally, then probably you should change the filetype of your file (in P4V, right-click | change Filetype | Base Filetype = Unicode or UTF-16 as appropriate).

Comment: You can use 'p4 files //files/of/interest/...' to examine the current filetypes of the files of interest.

Comment: OK so it looks like the files are of type utf-16 in the perforce repository, so when they get checked out from TeamCity and copied over to the build agent somehow they are getting changed to utf-8. Not sure why this would be happening, I am wondering if it is something to do with how the teamcity perforce is setup?